# Vertical centring image with display table-cell not working

Tags: css

Im trying to vertically centre an image using CSS display table-cell. WHy is my code not working? It looks like it should according to css-tricks.css

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

http://jsfiddle.net/sNE4y/1/

```
.cont {
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
img {
       display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
<div class="cont">
    <img src="http://www.quarktet.com/Icon-small.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The img tag doesn't need `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` its parent does.

So you need:

```
.cont {
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {

}
<div class="cont">
    <img src="http://www.quarktet.com/Icon-small.jpg" />
</div>
```

Also, it appears that `position: fixed` is giving this problems, as well, and I had to remove that to get it to work here:  http://jsfiddle.net/sNE4y/6/

If you still need `position: fixed;` (I'm assuming you do) then perhaps you need another parent div, but that all depends on how you want it designed.